# wpa_supplicant - no control interface generated under /run/wpa_supplicant

Tags: arch-linux, wpa-supplicant

I have an Arch Linux install, with wpa_supplicant.  Im trying to access through wpa_cli but get a connection error.  I suspect that the problem is that the `wpa_supplicant` is not generating a control interface under `/run`.

How would I get this working in a way where the control interface is created?

Running the commands output the following:

```
[connor@archlinux ~]$ wpa_cli 
wpa_cli v2.6
Copyright (c) ...
Interactive mode
Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (nil) - re-trying

[connor@archlinux ~]$ ls /run/w* 
ls: cannot access '/run/w*': No such file or directory

[connor@archlinux ~]$ ps aux | grep wpa
root      1565  0.0  0.0  16280  2200 ?        Ss   17:36   0:00 /usr/bin/wpa_supplicant -u -O /run/wpa_supplicant
connor    1571  0.0  0.0   3044   880 pts/1    S+   17:36   0:00 grep wpa
```

I also have a config (running with `wpa_supplicant -u -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`) with the contents:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

But have the same results as above.

Comment: I don't know how wpa_supplicant is typically started on Arch, but first thing I'd do is `ps` to see the arguments, stop it, and then run it from the commandline with the same arguments to see what happens, and debug it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wpa_supplicant only creates control interfaces during the initialization of a network interface (as specified by the `-i` option). You're not specifying any, so the relevant code is never called.

Also, you are running the wpa_supplicant service in "D-Bus control" (`-u`) mode, which is meant to be driven by other programs (such as NetworkManager) through the D-Bus interface. This is probably not the mode you want.

Use `wpa_supplicant@<ifname>.service` to run the daemon in regular mode, which will attach to the specified network adapter and load `wpa_supplicant-<ifname>.conf`.